# Replace specific variables in external bash-script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I am new to coding and already found a few topics about this on stackoverflow, but couldn't make it work, as they seem overextended to me. I might need some guidance.

I need to change some variables in an external bash script 'comlink.conf'. But only specific ones. Others should be left like they are.

```html
ready=0
test=1
new=2

echo 'ready='$ready > comlink.conf
sleep 10

ready=1

echo 'ready='$ready > comlink.conf
```

If I do it like that, 'test=1' and 'new=2' will be overwritten completely and are gone from the file. That should not happen.

What would be the most easiest way to do this?

Comment: when you use > in echo it overwrites the content in comlink.conf. If you want to add data you could use >>.

Comment: Great idea! But then 'ready' is 0 and in the next line it is 1. I need to update the specific variable, not add the same again with a different value, because another script will read and use the variables in that file.

Comment: You should look at a tool like `sed` for something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` with a different substitution like:

```
sed 's/ready=.*/ready=1/' comlink.conf > tmp
mv tmp comlink.conf
```

or if you are using GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/ready=.*/ready=1/' comlink.conf
```

or BSD sed:

```
sed -i'' 's/ready=.*/ready=1/' comlink.conf
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you!!! But why is it only working with a temp file? Is it not possible to edit an external file directly?

Comment: @daniel_e the versions of `sed` with `-i` support will modify it in-place.  If you try to use redirection though, you'll end up truncating the file before reading it, so you need a temp file (or something that works like it)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the info, Eric. Now I learned something. :-)

Comment: @daniel_e to be honest, the `-i` options do a temp file solution too instead of directly in place (which can matter if you have a full disk for example).  If you need real in place editing you can use a tool like `ed`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to replace a line in a file. You shouldn't use **echo** for that.

Instead I would suggest using sed:

```
sed '/.*ready*/s/.*/ready=1/' comlink.conf
```